# Need to rerender component on array prop update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have parent component ComponentTableCustom which is drawing tables according to given props. Also I have prop columnsNaryad which is array of objects. As a child CN has search field with button. How can I redraw CTC on this button click and get info from field?

What I have now:

```
export const columnsNaryad = [
    {
        title: 'Title',
        dataIndex: 'naryad_NomerNaryada',
        sorter: true,
        filter: '',
        children: [
            {
                title: (
                    <Input.Search
                        style={{ width: "100%" }}
                        onSearch={nameSearch => {
                            console.log(nameSearch)
                            console.log(columnsNaryad)
                            columnsNaryad[0].filter = nameSearch
                        }}
                    />
                ),
                dataIndex: 'naryad_NomerNaryada',
                width: 130,
            }
        ]
    },
    {...}]
```

And App:

```
<Route path="/naryad">
                <ComponentTableCustom
                  dataSource={naryad}
                  setDataSource={setDataSourceEdinicy}
                  columns={columnsNaryad}
                  page={"naryad"}
                  rowSelection
                />
</Route>
```

As a variant there is use-deep-compare-effect but that is not the best choise I think.

Comment: do you have a filter for each column, or is it only for the first `Title` column ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé for each

Comment: you need to store the filters into a state variable using `useState`. After that you should call the `setter` inside the `onSearch`.

Comment: @OlivierBoissé it could be great but CN is just exported array, which is importing in App. So any hooks are not allowed inside